# Unable to Call Instantiate in Class Member Function

Tags: unity

The following javascript is attached to a gameObject.

```
var instance : GameObject;

class eg_class   {   
    function eg_func(){    
       var thePrefab : GameObject;
        instance = Instantiate(thePrefab);
    }
}
```

Error,

> Unknown identifier: 'instance'.
>   Unknown identifier: 'Instantiate'.

Questions,

1) Why is it that "instance" cannot be accessed within a class? Isn't it supposed to be a public variable?
2) "Instantiate" function works in Start()/Update() root functions. Is there a way to make it work from within member functions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of things in your code backward. This is how it should be:

```
var thePrefab : GameObject;

class eg_class   {   
    function eg_func(){    
        var instance : GameObject;
        instance = Instantiate(thePrefab,transform.position,transform.rotation);
    }
}
```